# Writing a for loop in Python checking for divisibility

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to write a program in Python with turtle graphics to create a game. The game is built on blocks hovering in the air, where there is space between some of these blocks. The goal is to move a ball from the left side to the right without falling through the gaps.
I am experiencing some trouble with writing a for loop, that's counting from 0-20 (the amount of blocks) and if the number in the loop is divisible by 2 or 5 it will draw a block. (If not there will be a gap between the previous and next block)

Here is my code for the for loop:

```
def draw_blocks():
    for x in range(0, 21):
        if x % 5 == 0 or x % 2 == 0:
            draw_square(0, 0)     #starting index
            draw_square(square_size, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 2, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 3, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 4, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 5, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 6, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 7, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 8, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 9, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 10, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 11, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 12, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 13, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 14, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 15, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 16, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 17, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 18, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 19, 0)
            draw_square(square_size * 20, 0)
```

The draw_square function is defined as below:

```
def draw_square(x, y):
    turtle.tracer(0)
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.fillcolor("pink")
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.goto(x+square_size, y)
    turtle.goto(x+square_size, y-square_size)
    turtle.goto(x, y-square_size)
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.end_fill()
```

(Where square_size is a global variable with the value = 40.)

I'm thinking there is some issue with not defining each of draw_square statements in the for loop? Because right now I am only getting 20 blocks next to each other without any gaps.

Thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created draw_blocks incorrectly for what you are trying to do.

If you want it to only draw blocks when x is divisible by 2 or 5, you need to draw the block at the position of x times square_size. I've modified your draw_blocks function below, which fixes the issue:

```
def draw_blocks():
    for x in range(0, 21):
        if x % 5 == 0 or x % 2 == 0:
            draw_square(square_size*x, 0)
```